# Opencv windows 7 cmake mingw-32 make error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I wanted to ask about an error I got when compiling opencv for windows7, I am following this

http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml

and I have gotten to the part where both configure and generate commands on cmake are successful, but 
when using mingw32-make command in the directory where cmake builds opencv, I am getting the following error:

> fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory

this happens in the file windw_QT.h which is located on the sources folder in openc, my exact path is

C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\OpenCV248\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_QT.h

to be honest I could handle the cmake errors when it didn't know where to find the QT libraries, but I have no idea why compiling the sources yields this error, isn't QApplication supposed to exist in the very same folder as highgui.h

Comment: `isn't QApplication supposed to exist in the very same folder as highgui.h` -> It most probably is not. It would be useful if you could show the include path the compilre tries to use. Also, where exactly is your Qt installed?

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I did was upgrading to cmake 2.8 and everything solved. Although it is weird, and I have no explanation for that. Somewhere I read that cmake 2.6 has problems with md5, and even without checking the bool box WithQT it doesn't compile, and people solved that using 2.8.

Comment: carlos, OK, then. :) Which Qt version is it, btw?

Comment: I am using QT 5.2.1, best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you seem to have used cmake 2.6 for dealing with  Qt 5. If you take a look at the [Qt 5 cmake manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/cmake-manual.html), you can see that you would need at least 2.8.3, but 2.8.11 is recommended:

> CMake is a 3rd party tool with its own documentation. The rest of this manual details the specifics of how to use Qt 5 with CMake. The minimum version required to use Qt5 is CMake 2.8.3, but 2.8.11 is recommended.

Once you update, this all should start working.